# Record inserts into wrong table. Any ideas why and how to fix it?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This is very weird to me.

I tried to get the stored proc version of this code but with no success.

This is a Training app. Users must first register to create an account.

Then they use their accounts to sign up for class.

First the code checks to see if this user has already signed up for a particular class.

If no, then sign the user up. If yes, notify that user that s/he has already signed up.

This bit works.

If the user has not signed and is trying to sign up, check to see if there are still seats available. If yes, sign the user up. If no more seats are available, put the user on waiting list by inserting into a table called tblWaitinglist.

So far, each time I attemp to insert a new record, it says, class is full, user is being put on waiting list.

This is not true. Class is completely empty.

There are a total of 45 seats.

So far, all seats are available.

What the heck am I doing wrong?

It is not even inserting into waitinglist. It just gives the message that it did.

Please see my code below and thanks a lot in advance.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim username = Session("Username")
    Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
    conn.Open()
    Try

        Dim s As String
        Dim counter As Integer

        'If user already registered for a class, alert user
        s = "SELECT Count(*) FROM tblTrainings WHERE Username = '" & username & "' AND CourseID = " & Request.QueryString("cosId") & "  AND LocationID = " & Request.QueryString("locid") & " AND dateId = " & Request.QueryString("iddate") & ""
        'Response.Write(s)
        'Response.End()
        Dim connSt As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim connc As New SqlConnection(connSt)
        Dim cmdc As New SqlCommand(s, connc)
        connc.Open()
        cmdc.ExecuteNonQuery()
        counter = cmdc.ExecuteScalar()


        '   Now let's see if we found existing record of registration
        If counter = 0 Then 'User has not registered for this training. In that case, check to see there are still seats available.
            Dim SeatsAvailable As Integer
            SeatsAvailable = 0

            s = " SELECT SeatsAvailable = (Select Seating_Capacity  - (Select count(*) from tblTrainings where courseId = @cosId) from tblLocations WHERE LocationId = @Locid)"
            'Response.Write(s)
            'Response.End()
            Dim cmdB As New SqlCommand(s, conn)
            cmdB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cosID", Request.QueryString("cosId"))
            cmdB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@locID", Request.QueryString("locid"))
            cmdB.ExecuteNonQuery()


            If SeatsAvailable > 0 Then 'Ok there are still seats available. Sign this user up.
                s = "INSERT INTO tblTrainings (CourseId, LocationId, dateId,username) VALUES (@CosID, @LocID, @dat, @Username)"
                Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(s, conn)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cosID", Request.QueryString("cosId"))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@locID", Request.QueryString("locid"))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dat", Request.QueryString("iddate"))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", username)
                'Response.Write(s)
                'Response.End()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Dim cmdGetKey As New SqlCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY", conn)
                Dim skey As Integer = cmdGetKey.ExecuteScalar()
                Session("TrainingId") = skey
                conn.Close()
                confirmRegistraction()
                Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
                Label1.Text = "Congratulations! You have been registered for this class. Please check your email inbox for details"
            Else 'No seats remain. So, put user on waiting list
                s += "INSERT INTO tblWaitingList (CourseId, LocationId, dateId,username) VALUES (@CosID, @LocID, @dat, @Username)"
                Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(s, conn)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cosID", Request.QueryString("cosId"))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@locID", Request.QueryString("locid"))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dat", Request.QueryString("iddate"))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", username)
                'Response.Write(s)
                'Response.End()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Dim cmdGetKey As New SqlCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY", conn)
                Dim skey As Integer = cmdGetKey.ExecuteScalar()
                Session("TrainingId") = skey
                conn.Close()
                onWaitingList()
                'Display some feedback to the user to let them know it was processed
                Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
                Label1.Text = "Sorry, but this class is full. However, you have been placed on waiting list."
            End If

        Else
            'Alert user that s/he has already registered for this class
            Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
            Label1.Text = "You have already signed up for this training."
        End If

    Catch

        'If the message failed at some point, let the user know
        Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        Label1.Text = "Your record failed to save, please try again."

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: You should look at `using` or `try/catch/finally` to clean up your resources in your code.

Comment: The problems seems to be that `SeatsAvailable` is always 0. Have you tried debugging? Perhaps because you never assign it anything else than 0? `s = " SELECT SeatsAvailable [...]"` does not magically write the output of the query into the variable named `SeatsAvailable`, you'll have to assign it from the query results. Unfortunately you call `ExecuteNonQuery()` which doesn't allow you to do that.

Comment: First @CodeCaster, sorry for the wall of code and text. Sometimes, it is hard to tell when enough is enough because always comes up and say,"not enough information or code"

To answer your question, SeatsAvailable is not always 0. If I run that query on SSMS, it outputs correct value, in this case, 45.

Also, as stated, even when it says, you have been put on waitinglist, a record is supposed to be inserted into waitinglist table. None is getting inserted into the table.

Comment: Your program does not run the query in SSMS. It also doesn't assign the result of the query to anything. Put a breakpoint. Inspect the `SeatsAvailable` variable. See it **is** always 0. Take a look at the `ExecuteScalar()` method.

Comment: FYI, this isn't really using a stored proc since you're still using in-line SQL.

Comment: Some folks don't really take their time to read. I said in my original post that I had tried using stored proc but was having problem with it and decided to use embedded sql. Maybe my original explanation wasn't nearly as simplistic as this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are never setting SeatsAvailable to anything other than zero.  Your s variable is probably what you want to be looking at.

The failure to INSERT is another issue altogether.

Comment: @Dourglas and CodeCaster, actually I was wrong about one thing.

Records are getting inserted into WaitingList table and yes the message is correct.

The issue though is that it should be inserting into Training table when SeatsAvailable is greater than 0.

Is my logic wrong?

Comment: I got it now to work. I removed the SeatsAvailable=0 and used this instead:

SeatsAvailable = cmdB.ExecuteScalar() and it works. 

You guys are the greatest.

Thank you